# how to send image file through ajax load() function and insert in mysql db display in div through php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is form i am sending image file to the `upload.php` script file and image file should display in the 'onsuccessmsg' div

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" id="uploadform">
   <input type="file" file="file" id="file_to_send"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/><br/>
   Message :
   <div id="onsuccessmsg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;"></div>
  </form>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#uploadform").on('submit',function(){


        $("#onsuccessmsg").load("upload.php",{},function(res){

        });

});
});
</script>
```

This is the `upload.php` file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, "./uploads/".$imgn))
    {
     echo "File Name : ".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     echo "<br/>File Temporary Location : ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     echo "<br/>File Size : ".$_FILES['file']['size'];
     echo "<br/>File Type : ".$_FILES['file']['type'];
     echo "<br/>Image : <img style='margin-left:10px;' src='uploads/".$imgn."'>";
    }
}

?>
```

Onsubmit the form how to send the name and id values to the `upload.php` file and echoing the image file in the `onsuccessmsg` div,
I am confused, please help me.

Comment: This isn't answered with a few lines of codes. You should consider using a library which already supports Async-Uploads etc. eg: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: please let me know the code for uploading the files and display through the ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe for such upload of image with jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#input_for_image_upload").change(function()
    { 
       $("#img_upload").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the image name through this code

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    var str=$("#image").val();
    var arr=str.split("\\");
    var image=arr[2];
    alert(image);
});
```